# Get html content of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have stored a html in a variable using javascript now i need to fetch particular div value from that variable using javascript

```
var colVal = $(this).jqGrid('getCell', rowid, iCol);
var element = colVal;
```

this is the output of **colVal**

```
<div style='text-align:center;'>
  <div>
    <input type='range' min='5' max='"10"' step='1' value='3' data-rangeslider>
    <output id='val'>2</output>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now i need to get that value 2 using id 'val'

Comment: `let value = $('div > #val').val();` \ `let value = $('output').val();`

Comment: `$(colVal).find("#id").val()`

Comment: `$(colVal).find("#val").html()`, `$(colVal)` creates HTML elements from HTML string, then you can use `jQuery` functions in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(_this).attr('data-id');
```

you can get the value of the html attribute where data-id is the name of the attribute

Comment: what will be the data-id

Comment: just a attritube inside a html tag where u store information like this i append inside my html setting the data-id value whit the variable inside e.dnominazione <input data-id ="' + e.denominazione + '" type="checkbox" class="js-switch"/>

Answer (score -1):

```
element.getElementById('val').innerHTML
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.